# Does GNU Global/gtags support taglist vim plugin?

Tags: vim, taglist, gnu-global

I did some searches, but did not find anything useful. Could someone refer me to some links or give instructions directly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept to use vim's cscope interface, Gnu global comes with gtags-cscope which offers the same interface as cscope but backed by global's database.
Just set cscopeprg=gtags-cscope and you'll be able to navigate across tags.

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I've just decided to finally try [GNU GLOBAL](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/) about an hour ago.

`gtags` is not in TagList's default executables. So it's not "supported".

Maybe you can add it via `let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd='/path/to/gtags'` but I doubt `gtags` accepts the same arguments as `ctags` or even if it can output its index to stdout like `ctags` which is what is used by TagList.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this way. It did not work. :(

Comment: gtags can be configured to output in ctags format. With tagbar.vim, for each filetype you can configure the desired command to run to get the ctag file.  So you could use gtags if you wanted - but it would still be the ctag format that you'd be using. Usually you wouldn't use a different ctags program unless it had better language support. For example jsctags is popular for javascript.

Comment: You are right but neither TagList nor TagBar use actual `tags` files. Both use `ctags` (and `jsctags` and others) ability to send output to `-`. I've looked at `gtags` doc this morning but, aside from the promising `ctags` compatibility I don't see anywhere a mention of `stdout`. Anyway, I didn't manage to make it work with JavaScript so I won't go further with this case.